# Drupal UberCart how can users see thier own orders

Tags: ubercart

I'm setting up a shop on one of my sites, and I've set it so users create an account when they order. When users log in, I cannot workout the link to show their past orders, or registered addresses.

Is there anything built into UberCart for this? All I've found are some permissions and I've set "View own order." Do I have to write up a module for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the users are not anonymous users, they should have a tab in their user profile that shows their orders.

Comment: ah! splendid. couldn't see the wood for the trees! thanks.